# Conditionally open url in new tab via js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a survey-like web application where a user selects a number of checkboxes  and then presses "Submit" button-like link

```
<!-- page: /survey -->
<form id="survey" method="post" action="/complete">
    <!-- checkboxes, etc here -->
    <a id="submit" class="button" href="#">Submit</a>
</form>
<script>
    $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //... other staff happens here
        $('#survey').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Then the form is processed on the server and results are shown to the user on `/complete` page.

What I want to achieve is to *conditionally* open a new tab after form was submitted. This condition and the url of the tab will be determined on the server after the survey was submitted.

I can make it work unconditionally if I plug `window.open('...', '_blank')` into the click-event handler on the initial `/survey` page:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //... other staff happens here
    window.open('http://example.com', '_blank'); // <---- this line
    $('#survey').submit();
});
```

It fails though, if I use `window.open` on the `/complete` page: a popup warning appears instead. Probably because it is not connected to any user-initiated event.

In my case, however, there is a user-initiated event, but it happened on a previous page. Is there any way I can pass this event to the new page (obviously new page is on the same domain name, protocol, etc). Probably there is another way?

Comment: There isn't enough information provided to really give a best-solution. However, some ideas are to: 1) Conditionally show the user a link on the following page to open the window (and prevent popup blockers). 2) Show the popup on the same page by implementing an AJAX call and conditionally showing the popup before redirecting.

Comment: Why are you using a link instead of `<button type="submit">`?

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do what you're after is to change the markup:

```
<form id="survey" method="post" action="/complete">
    <!-- checkboxes, etc here -->
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then in JavaScript, listen for the `submit` event. This will allow native features—such as implicit submission (enter key in a text field), or middle-clicking on the submit button—to work by default.

Now here're some important parts:

- only prevent the default behavior if the input is invalid
- if you want the form to open in a new tab, change the `target` attribute of the form.

```
$('#survey').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!checkValidity(...)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    //other stuff happens

    var newTab = shouldOpenInNewTab(...);
    $(this).attr('target', newTab ? '_blank' : '');
});
```

Doing that will allow the browser to use its default behaviors. It's cross-browser compatible, and it's accessible.